# Force element.innerHTML update before javascript sort call

Tags: javascript, progress-bar

what is the best practice for this scenario:
1) User clicks "Sort huge javascript array"
2) Browser shows "Sorting..." through element.innerHTML="Sorting"
3) Browser sorts huge javascript array (100% CPU for several seconds) while displaying "Sorting..." message.
4) Browser shows result.

Pseudo code:

```
...
<a href="#" onclick="sortHugeArray();return false">Sort huge array</a>
...
function sortHugeArray(){
  document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="Sorting...";
  ...do huge sort ...
  ...render result...
  document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML=result;
}
```

When i do that this way, browser never shows "Sorting...", it freezes browser for several seconds and shows result without noticing user...

Thank you for advice.

Comment: Bobince's answer is spot on.  As for best practices for connecting events, see PPK's http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to return control to the browser to let it update any changes on-screen. Use a timeout to ask it to return control to you.

```
function sortHugeArray(){
    document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML="Sorting...";
    setTimeout(function() {
        ...do huge sort ...
        ...render result...
        document.getElementById("progress").innerHTML=result;
    }, 0);
}
```

It's a bit questionable to be executing a script for ‘several seconds’, though. There should be a way to speed that up, or break the process into parts returning control with a timeout every so often to keep the page responsive.

Comment: OK, thank you. So there is no any other way than using setTimeout?