# Javascript: how to update page before onClick is complete?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a function that's designed to parse a 20MB XML file. It works well, but I'd like to give some progress indication during the minute or so it takes.

This, however, doesn't work:

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

function pauseJS(timeInMilliS) {
    var date = new Date();
    var curDate = null;
    do { curDate = new Date(); }
    while(curDate-date < timeInMilliS);
}

function process() {
    for (var i = 0; i<=10; i++) {
        document.images["bar"].width += 5;
        document.images["bar"].height = 5;      
        pauseJS(500);
    }
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" value="Go" onClick="process()"> 
    <img src="black.gif" name="bar" width=1 height=5 />
</body>
```

(pauseJS stands in for the processing)
The progress bar would only update once processing is done, not during.

I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795517/force-element-innerhtml-update-before-javascript-sort-call), but setTimeout doesn't seem to help in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` is exactly how you deal with this, but you have to structure your parsing function correctly. The *last* thing you want to do is the busy-wait shown in `pauseJS`. That doesn't pause JavaScript, that makes JavaScript run maniacally until the time is reached or the browser cancels the script for being over-consumptive. :-)

To allow the browser a moment to update the page display, you must make the JavaScript thread yield back to the browser. So for instance, this will not work:

```
var TOTAL = 10000000;
var BATCH = 10000;

function doSomething() {
    for (n = 0; n < TOTAL; ++n) {
        if ((n % BATCH) == 0) {
            // ...change progress indicator...
        }

        // ...do processing...
    }
}
```

...because it never yields. This, on the other hand, works:

```
var TOTAL = 10000000;
var BATCH = 10000;

function doSomething() {
    var n = 0;

    work();

    function work() {
        var maxn = Math.min(n + BATCH, TOTAL);

        for ( ; n < maxn; ++n) {
            // ...do processing...
        }

        // ...update progress indicator...

        if (n < TOTAL) {
            setTimeout(work, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, here we're breaking the work up into discrete batches, and periodically stopping, scheduling the next batch of work, and returning control to the browser. This gives it a moment to update the page, after which it will call us back (not after 0ms literally, but when it next can, which will typically be however it takes to update itself plus 5-10ms).

Comment: Would there be a difference to using `setInterval()`? I guess just semantic.

Comment: @Jared: I would strongly recommend against `setInterval` in this case. `setInterval` fires periodically, but gets a bit chaotic when the function it calls takes longer to execute than the interval period. Some browsers just skip the next scheduled call, and so if your interval is (say) 30ms and you get called at +30ms, +60ms, and +90ms but for some reason your +120ms call takes 40ms to complete, overrunning the interval, you'll completely miss your +150ms call and have to wait for the +180ms. Other implementations may call you closer together. Rescheduled `setTimeout` is better in this case.

Comment: Thanks, TJ, and Evan's note about the single thread helps understand why it behaves like that.

Comment: The question is, then, how to make a script do a lot of work without a loop?? In my case e.g. I have 1000 XML nodes to parse, that'd be the best way to break down the progress into precentage or other user notification, but how would I process them without looping/iterating through them?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has only one thread, meaning there's no way you can do more than one thing at once.

You'll have to break the XML processing function up so it does a chunk of work, updates the progress bar, and so on.